# Swagger Query Parameter based on enum value

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

In my node application, I'm using swagger, in that for a particular GET route, in query, I am using enum

```
get:
 *      description: Validation Option
 *      tags:
 *          - Validation User and Supplier
 *      parameters:
 *          - in: query
 *            name: document_type
 *            type: string
 *            minLength: 1
 *            maxLength: 20
 *            description: type of document used
 *            enum:
 *              - GST
 *              - PAN
```

```
Query String:

/?document_type=GST&gst_number=AHUIHGION&mobile=90890893
/?document_type=PAN&pan_number=HIIHE3289
```

Here when the document_type is GST means, it should show the certain fields, if PAN means certain fields, based on enum selection the query parameters should change. How can I achieve this?